# How can i fetch data sequentially each row on each iteration fron csv file config on j meter

Tags: jmeter

I have set 4 virtual user on thread group and i have set csv file config having 2 rows of data.when i run the test the first iteration 2 virtual user is fetching data sequentially but in the next iteration the remaining 2 virtual user is fetching ramdom data not sequentially.I want to fetch data sequentially on the next iteration (1 user->first row,2 user->second row) next itetation(3user->first row,4user->second row) how can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve this using CSV Data Set Config as in case of concurrency you might run into the situation when pre-allocated entry for the user will be not sequential when it comes to test results.

If you want to have the following sequence:

- line 1
- line 2
- line 1
- line 2

no matter how many users/iterations you have and what is response times fluctuation you need to consider switching to [__StringFromFile()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) or [__CSVRead()](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-pick-different-csv-files-at-jmeter-runtime/) functions instead of CSV Data Set Config

[image]

Comment: I did the same but i got the this result on view result tree.I kept the csv file on jmeter bin folder also .I think its not taking csv file.    Result:User:2,Iteration:1,Line from CSV: $(__StringFromFile(client.csv,,,)}

Comment: The correct syntax is `${__StringFromFile(client.csv,,,)}` 

If you're uncertain regarding the syntax you can double check using [Function Helper Dialog](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#function_helper) under "Tools" section of the JMeter Main menu.

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction)